# how can I check if event listener is fired when I open chrome dev tool and set responsive size

Tags: javascript

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVuB6.png)Every time I open chrome dev tools with responsive resizing, event listener like 'click', 'mouseover' aren't fired.(Or just aren't showing on screen).
For example,
as a picture I attached, I implemented menu bar(icon on right top) with click event for responsive. When I click menu bar, it's supposed to be opened. But nothing happens on responsive screen.
It seems like it's working since console.log('click') in this function is working.

How can I check and see visually if event listener is fired while I open dev tool with responsive screen? I didn't implement this click event for full screen so I need to check this event on responsive size.

Another example,
mouse event doesn't show on responsive screen. But full size, it does as a second picture I attached. So I can check at least if this event is actually working.

I have been trying to figure it out but I can't find solution.
I would be grateful if someone could give me advise. Thank you.

[image: example1 menubar click event]
[image: example2 mouse event]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSH8o.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSH8o.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmLuw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmLuw.png)

Comment: "When I click menu bar, it's supposed to be opened. But nothing happens on responsive screen. It seems like it's working since console.log('click') in this function is working." — Well, if the log is firing then that means the click is working. It's the code which opens the menu that isn't. We can't help you with that based on the information you've provided. You need to read [ask] and provide a [mcve] using the [live demo feature of the question editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0):

without any code it's quite difficult to answer your question!
perhaps it's a question of "element" clicked. If the click handler is on one element but in fact it's another element which is really clicked (DOM structure). Dev tools doesn't show anything.

you can put the following function in your code.
this function is at body level to check which element has been clicked.
if the clicked element doesn't have any handler, the event goes up to the body and you'll have in console the target and the currentTarget.

perhaps that can help...

```
/**
 * Body click. bubbling
 */
document.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log(evt.target);
    console.log(evt.currentTarget);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I put this in my code. And I got <i id="bar" class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i> and # document in console.

Comment: that means the clicked element is the id bar. Is it the one you have a handler on? If yes, it's something else! Is it working in landscape and not in portrait?

Comment: Yes I have a handler on id bar. It's not working in landscape and not in portrait. When I apply The Toggle Device Toolbar in dev tool, I can't see event working visually...